# Computability of the function $P(x)=\varphi_x(x)$

Tags: computability

Let $P$ be the predicate on natural numbers defined by $P(x) \iff \varphi_x(x) = 1$ where $\varphi_x$ is the $x$-th computable function. Show that $P$ is not computable.

Comment: This is a homework dump, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the phrasing of the problem or a step in your solution attempts, please edit the question and we can reopen.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard argument by diagonalization. Let the $x$-th computable map be $\varphi_x$.

Suppose $P$ were computable, which by definition means that the following function $p$ is computable:
$p(x) = (\mathsf{if}\ \varphi_x(x) = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0)$.
Therefore the function $f(x) = 1 - p(x)$ is computable also. There is a number $y$ such that $\varphi_y = f$. Either $p(y) = 0$ or $p(y) = 1$:

- if $p(y) = 0$ then
  $$0 = p(y) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ \varphi_y(y) = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ 1 - p(y) = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ 1 - 0 = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ \mathsf{true} \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = 1,$$
  a contradiction.
- similarly, if $p(y) = 1$ then 
  $$1 = p(y) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ \varphi_y(y) = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ 1 - p(y) = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ 1 - 1 = 1 \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = \\
  (\mathsf{if}\ \mathsf{false} \ \mathsf{then}\ 1 \ \mathsf{else}\ 0) = 1,$$
  a contradiction.

We have reached a contradiction, so our initial assumption that $P$ is computable is fasle.